# Export of JIRA issues and dashboards for exec presentations

Tags: export, powerpoint, jira

I use Jira for project management in my projects, however we have to produce ppt presentations for executives and high-level managers which take a bit of time to assemble.

I would like to automate the production of Powerpoints for my projects that would easily take key information either by choosing the fields or linking some data to a ppt template.

**=> Is there a simple way or any add-on to do it that has any success currently ?**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps export the Jira data into CSV, import into Excel and then follow
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d